# Long open/save for entries with 10-column Matrix fields

Tags: add-on, matrix, mysql

I am moving over a thread started on P&T's [Get Satisfaction](http://gsfn.us/t/3h77q).

I am getting a MySQL timeout saving an entry that had a 10-column Matrix field and some 70 rows. Raising the MySQL limits fixes the immediate problem (we can save), but seems to point at a bigger underlying issue -- entries take a surprisingly long time to save and open, while showing relatively normal benchmarks in EE's debugging panel.

To isolate the problem, I set up a separate, fresh EE install with Matrix as my only plugin. I then created a single channel field with a Matrix of 10 text-only columns.

In this environment, an entry with a single Matrix with 100 rows took 47 seconds to save. However, an entry with 8 Matrix of 13 rows each (104 total rows) took 7 seconds to save. More interesting, the benchmarks for Loading Time, Total Execution Time, and Controller Execution Time were all very reasonable (0.2 to 0.4 or so).

I would like to keep these entries in a single Matrix table, if possible. Is this just an effect of saving a table with this many cells (and a natural limit of EE, Matrix, or MySQL). Or is there's something else at play?

Any insights?

Comment: Can you share the info from EE's debugging panel? E.g. memory usage and number of queries for each respective page load would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. I took apart the test install debugging this afternoon. I am rebuilding it tonight, but in the meantime can point to stats from the  the dev environment. 

Note, the Matrix is a lot more complex, with a fiesta of P&T's field types, including an Asset field, Wygwam field, and dropdown. These numbers are higher therefore than the test environment. 

Loading Time: Base Classes -- 0.0181
Total Execution Time -- 0.8831
Controller Execution Time ( Content Publish / Entry Form ) -- 0.8662

Memory usage is all the way up to 24 MB.

Comment: Also note, it is an entry with 79 rows: Script executed in 0.8831 seconds - 219 SQL queries used


It takes a solid 25-ish seconds to load and/or save.

Comment: Has there been any other updates to the performance issues? I am running a site which has over 100 matrix rows per entry (with 4 columns per row) and saving times are abysmal (can be over 120 seconds). I understand P&T is working full tilt on Craft, I just wish there was some love shown to EE Matrix :( matrix 2.6.1 ExpressionEngine 2.9.2 Build 20141004 jQuery 1.7.2 MySQL 5.6.21-log Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 PHP 5.6.3 register_globals off safe_mode off open_basedir max_execution_time 300 upload_max_filesize 50M max_input_time 900 memory_limit 128M session_save_path writable

Comment: From the changelog, it looks like 2.6 did not include performance improvements. Can you create a workaround -- duplicate fields for each entry and cycle through the fields in the template, etc.?

Comment: I think I may have to.  I am weighing the pros and cons of that vs. redoing it with the built-in grid fieldtype :/
Either way, it will be extra work that I would rather put towards adding new features.

Comment: I would be curious to see what your experience is with the grid field type if you go that route -- if it's any more efficient. I believe EllisLabs took a "very similar" approach to P&T, although I haven't used/tested that field type at all to know. I wouldn't bet my farm on it, but maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good answer to this issue by Brandon over at the original GetSatisfaction entry: 
https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/error_2006_on_submit

Thanks again, Brandon.

Comment: Shanan - that getsatisfaction link is dead. Can you share what the fix was?

Comment: Unfortunately, there wasn't a solution. Brandon noted that they were making significant edits to the module with a focus on performance. In the meantime, our fix was to create multiple duplicates of our Matrix field and cycle through those. A workaround, but functional. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you’re running the latest version of Matrix. Matrix 2.5 came with a pretty drastic performance boost.

http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix/releasenotes

Comment: The test install is v2.5.3 of EE and 2.5.2 of Matrix running on MAMP (MySQL 5.5.9 and PHP 5.3.5).