# Can't save large matrix field

Tags: matrix, assets

I'm having a problem similar to [this one](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/long-open-save-for-entries-with-10-column-matrix-fields) where I can't save large matrix fields on my site. Large, in this case, is > 200 rows with 3 fields each where 2 of those are asset fields. EE/Matrix/Assets/Fieldpack are all up-to-date and I've increased max_input_vars to 1500, max_execution_time to 600 and memory_limit to 256; still no luck. I just get a blank screen, no error message, no error in logfile.

Should I just stop trying to use matrix for this and adopt a different design, or should this work?

Answer (score 2):

1) read server logs
2) turn debugging on in index.php

This should help you understand better where the problem is.

I have lots of issues like that and Usually it is a matter of server configuration but you must start reading and identifying the error from logs

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with more memory or higher max_execution_time? I'm running 1024M. Also max_input_time:60

When I had problems with that on one site I had the max_execution_time lifted to 12000 & its fine but I've never used that many Matrix rows.

I think you *should* be able to get this working but may need to have the available server resources cranked up.

Comment: Thanks Damien - I tried increasing all these php config values but no luck. Previously I was getting errors in my PHP log file about exceeding the number of input vars, but once I extended that I'm not getting any php debugging output - I have a feeling I'm encountering a webserver process timeout here.

Comment: Sorry to hear that didn't work. For what its worth, I put all of my EE sites on Nexcess shared hosting & have very few of these types of issues compared to cPanel hosting. Might not be the solution but could be worth spinning up a dev account to see if it gets you out of the jam.